# How to declare an object of arrays in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm working with Angular 4 and I want to declare a in component class an attribute, which is an object containing multiple arrays, like the following.

```
history: {
  Movies: Array<Media>,
  Images: Array<Media>,
  Music: Array<Media>,
};
```

The Media is an interface that looks like the following:

```
export interface Media {
  size: number,
  name: String
}
```

When I try to push an object history elements like:

```
this.history.Music.push(music);
```

Given that `music` has the same type (Media).

It gives me the following error :

> 1449 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Music' of undefined

I guess that has something to do with the declaration.

Note: I've already tried something like:

```
history: {
  Movies: Array<Media>[],
  Images: Array<Media>[],
  Music: Array<Media>[],
};
```

And:

```
history: {
  Movies: Media[],
  Images: Media[],
  Music: Media[],
};
```

And the same error remains.

Comment: It sounds like your `history` property hasn't been initialized yet, that's not a TypeScript error, that's a runtime error.

Comment: Ok , can you please mention how am i supposed to initialize it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize `history` object as follows, along with all the properties being set to `empty` array

```
history: {Movies: Array<Media>, Images: Array<Media>, Music: Array<Media>} = {
  Movies: [],
  Images: [],
  Music: []
};
```

Comment: That will just cause another `TypeError` due to `Music` being `undefined`. Why not initialize it

Comment: maybe it should be like this ?, i tried it and it didn't gives any error 
`history: {Movies:Array<Media>,Images:Array<Media>,Music:Array<Media>} = {Movies:[],Images:[],Music:[]};`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a History class:

```
class History {
    constructor(public Movies: Media[] = [], public Images: Media[] = [], public Music: Media[] = []){}
}
```

Then in your component, you can initialize your `history` property like this:

```
history = new History();
```

then you can do what you tried to do:

```
this.history.Music.push(music);
```

Comment: I think this is a valid option too. If the OP would not like to use a whole new class, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51162387/how-to-declare-an-object-of-arrays-in-typescript/51162802#51162802) could be an option.